# Does HtmlAgilityPack have the ability to use regular expressions in its XPATH selector?

Tags: c#, regex, xpath, html-agility-pack

I would like to be able to create a collection of nodes where the text starts with a word and then a number.  For example, given the following:

```
<p>FINDTHIS 1</p>
<p>FINDTHIS SOMETEXT</p>
<p>FINDTHIS 2</p>
```

I would like to be able to create a collection consisting of two paragraph nodes: FINDTHIS 1 and FINDTHIS 2.

One possible approach would be to create an xpath query like `//p[starts-with(., 'FINDTHIS ')]` and then use a regular expression to determine whether or not the next character is a number.  If I wanted to obtain a list of matches that returned the above criteria, I could create a regular expression object and test the text for each member in the collection.

Is there a way to utilize a regular expression directly within the selector using HtmlAgilityPack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) does not currently support this.  It supports [XPath version 1 queries, which does not support regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/405507/50776).

That said, you'll have to do as you recommended and select using the XPath expression up to the point where you want to use a regular expression, and then use the [`Where` extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx) to filter out the appropriate nodes based on an [`RegEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) instance.

Answer (score 1):

It's not available out-of-the-box, but you can add this functionality easily. It's described here: [HtmlAgilityPack: xpath and regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744559/htmlagilitypack-xpath-and-regex)