# Beginner Python Question RE: String Formatting Type and repr() function

Tags: python, string-conversion

So I have this code:

```
    formatter = "%r %r %r %r"

print formatter % (1, 2, 3, 4)
print formatter % ("one", "two", "three", "four")
```

And I get this output:

1 2 3 4

'one' 'two' 'three' 'four'

---

My question is:

**Why does the second line of output have single quotes around it? I'm not quite sure how the %r conversion type really works.**

When I change the code to:

```
formatter = "%r %r %r %r"

print formatter % (1, 2, 3, 4)
print "%s %s %s %s" % ("one", "two", "three", "four")
```

I get this result:

1 2 3 4

one two three four

**I just don't understand why they work differently. Can someone break it down for me?**

---

I've read:

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html &

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr

Comment: This is a good question, particularly if you are a beginner. Then I upvoted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the expression `'abc%rdef' % obj` , the part `'%r'` is replaced with `repr(obj)`

With the expression `'ABC%sDEF' % obj` , the part `'%s'` is replaced with `str(obj)`

.

**repr()** is a function that , for common objects, returns a string that is the same as the one you would write in a script to define the object passed as argument to the **repr()** function:

> For many types, this function makes an attempt to return a string that
>   would yield an object with the same value when passed to eval()
>   http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr

.

> Example 1

if you consider the list defined by `li = [12,45,'haze']`

`print li` will print *[12,45,'haze']*

`print repr(li)` will also print *[12,45,'haze']* , because `[12,45,'haze']` is the sequence of characters that are written in a script to define the list **li** with this value

> Example 2

if you consider the string defined by `ss = 'oregon'` :

`print ss` will print *oregon* , without any quote around

`print repr(ss)` will print *'oregon'* , since `'oregon'` is the sequence of characters that you must write in a script if you want to define the string **ss** with the value *oregon* in a program

.

So, this means that , in fact, for common objects, **repr()** and **str()** return strings that are in general equal, except for a string object. That makes **repr()** particularly interesting for string objects. It is very useful to analyse the contents of HTML codes, for exemple.

Comment: Ooooo! And the lightbulb goes on. This is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an examples of how it's "useful to analyse the contents of HTML codes."

Comment: @Dorje Yes. Read first this post: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213970/python-url-variable-int-add-to-string/7214095#7214095) In the second part of the post, there is this instruction ``li = htmlcode.splitlines(True)`` followed by this other useful instruction ``print '\n'.join(str(i) + ' ' + repr(line)+'\n' for i,line in enumerate(li) if 275<i<300)`` that displays a very useful representation of a portion of the content of an HTML code. Delete the portion ``if 275<i<300`` and you obtain a rpresentation of the whole content of the HTML fetched code.

Comment: @Dorje More complex and more in relation to your question is this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206143/python-regex-problem/7207746#7207746)

Comment: @Dorje By the way, re-reading the docs concerning **repr()**, it reminded me that we can write ``print `x` `` instead of ``repr(x)``

Comment: @Dorje And I realize that it is better to write ``print '\n'.join('%s %r\n' % (i,line) for i,line in enumerate(li)`` . Or even like that: ``print '\n'.join(map(lambda x:'%s %r\n' % x, enumerate(ch.splitlines(True))))``

Comment: Wow. I can see why that's useful. Everything you've add here will be useful for me to pull apart and learn. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`%s` tell's python to call the `str()` function on each element of your tuple. `%r` tell's python to call the `repr()` function on each element of your tuple.

By the docs:

[str()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#str):

> Return a string containing a **nicely** printable
>   representation of an object. For strings, this returns the string
>   itself.

[repr()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr):

> Return a string containing a **printable** representation of an object.

This means, if the object you call `repr()` on is a string object (in python everything is an object) it shows you how the different characters are represented.

@your specific question: I assume that the "..." indicate, that it is a string. If you call repr() on an int there are no "...".

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This really helped explain the docs more. "This means, if the object you call repr() on is a string object (in python everything is an object) it shows you how the different characters are represented."