# PhP Find (and replace) string between two different strings

Tags: php, regex, string, replace

I have a string, that look like this `"<html>"`. Now what I want to do, is get all text between the `"<"` and the `">"`, and this should apply to any text, so that if i did `"<hello>"`, or `"<p>"` that would also work. Then I want to replace this string with a string that contains the string between the tags.
For example
In:

```
<[STRING]>
```

Out:

```
<this is [STRING]>
```

Where [STRING] is the string between the tags.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: i'd say you should take a look at regular expressions, but you already tagged them. so instead i'm gonna ask: and what have you *tried* so far?

Comment: [Are you parsing html with a regular expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1641867) - don't think thats a good idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex - Matching Tag Names Only in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181653/regex-matching-tag-names-only-in-html)

Answer (score 2):

Use a capture group to match everything after `<` that isn't `>`, and substitute that into the replacement string.

```
preg_replace('/<([^>]*)>/, '<this is $1>/, $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution to test on the pattern exists and then capture it to finally modify it ...

```
<?php
$str = '<[STRING]>';
$pattern = '#<(\[.*\])>#';

if(preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches)):
    var_dump($matches);
    $str = preg_replace($pattern, '<this is '.$matches[1].'>', $str);
endif;

echo $str;
?>
```

echo $str; 
You can test here: http://ideone.com/uVqV0u

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can be usefull to you.
You can use a  **regular expression** that is **the best way**. But you can also consider a little function that remove first `<` and last `>` char from your string.

This is my solution:

```
<?php

/*Vars to test*/

$var1="<HTML>";
$var2="<P>";
$var3="<ALL YOU WANT>";

/*function*/

function replace($string_tag) {
$newString="";
for ($i=1; $i<(strlen($string_tag)-1); $i++){
    $newString.=$string_tag[$i];
}

return $newString;

}

/*Output*/

echo (replace($var1));
echo "\r\n";
echo (replace($var2));
echo "\r\n";
echo (replace($var3));

?>
```

Output give me:
HTML
P
ALL YOU WANT

Tested on https://ideone.com/2RnbnY